# ASP.net login timed out in salesforce

Tags: c#, asp.net, proxy, salesforce

I want to use the Enterprise WSDL service of Salesforce in my ASP.net application to import/export data to/of salesforce.
The service is already imported in my project as Service Reference and I can create Salesforce objects in my code behind(c#)

But when I try to login via the application, I get this timeout error:

> Message: The request channel timed out attempting to send after 00:01:00. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.
>
> Source: mscorlib
>
> Type: System.TimeoutException

My guess is that I need to setup a proxy to the Salesforce request, so does anybody know how to retrieve this?

This is what I have so far:

```
using (enterprise.SoapClient loginClient = new enterprise.SoapClient("Soap"))
        {
            string sfPassword = "password";
            string sfUsername = "my@email.com";

            enterprise.LoginResult result = loginClient.login(null, sfUsername, sfPassword);

            output.InnerHtml = "SessionID: " + result.sessionId + "<br />" +
                                "SessionURL: " + result.serverUrl;

        }
```

**Edit:**

https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_login.htm

Found this page which contains a code snippet to use a proxy. But the problem is that I don't have a ConnectorConfig or EnterpriseConnection at choice. Seems that this is the JAVA code, but I need the C# samples. Any ideas?

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added the Network Credentials line

```
using enterprise = NamespaceName.WebReferenceName;
using proxy = System.Net.WebProxy;
using System.Net;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        enterprise.SforceService sforceService = new enterprise.SforceService();
        proxy wp = new proxy("StringOfHost", 9999); //Host, Port
        wp.Credentials = new NetworkCredentials("username", "password");
        sforceService.Proxy = wp;
        enterprise.LoginResult loginResult = sforceService.login(sfUsername, sfPwd);
}
```